# Unity TextMesh Pro color tag ignored?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity C# with TextMesh Pro. When ticking Rich Text (and ensuring Override Tags is unticked), which I did, it's meant to allow [color tags](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#color) like

```
<color=#FF0000>* Susan has joined</color>
<color=#000000>Hello!</color>
```

I've also tried the various variants, like <#FF0000> etc. However, everything remains black for me (except in the Unity debug console, which also supports these color tags when Debug.Logging). Using the `<alpha=#44>` tag works fine, by the way. What to do? Thanks!

Comment: Check the material attached to the object with the TextMeshPro component, "Face" color should not be in black

Comment: Thank you, turning it e.g. white solved it! Feel free to post this as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the material attached to the object with the TextMeshPro component, "Face" color should not be in black. 
[image]